# PHP write binary response

Tags: php, binary, response

In php is there a way to write binary data to the response stream,

like the equivalent of (c# asp)

```
System.IO.BinaryWriter Binary = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(Response.OutputStream);
Binary.Write((System.Int32)1);//01000000
Binary.Write((System.Int32)1020);//FC030000
Binary.Close();
```

I would then like to be able read the response in a c# application, like

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("URI");
System.IO.BinaryReader Binary = new System.IO.BinaryReader(Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
System.Int32 i = Binary.ReadInt32();//1
i = Binary.ReadInt32();//1020
Binary.Close();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In PHP, strings and byte arrays are one and the same. Use `pack` to create a byte array (string) that you can then write. Once I realized that, life got easier.

```
$my_byte_array = pack("LL", 0x01000000, 0xFC030000);
$fp = fopen("somefile.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $my_byte_array);

// or just echo to stdout
echo $my_byte_array;
```

Comment: +1 for answer that helped me. I'm adding what worked for me below as another answer.

Comment: I prefer to use `print()` instead of `echo` because it's more like a function. Neither is technically a real function, though. The documentation calls them as "language constructs". It's also technically possible to do `fopen("php://output")` if you need file descriptor for output. For details, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen You can call `echo` the same way. `echo($my_byte_array);` is perfectly valid, as is `print $my_byte_array`. They are the same. It's not necessarily a good idea to use parentheses for either one, though, since it's not actually a function. You're not actually calling `print()` with a parameter of `$my_byte_array`, you're "calling" `print` with a "parameter" of `($my_byte_array)` (which is just an expression).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I use `chr()`;

```
echo chr(255); // Returns one byte, value 0xFF
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Answer (score 1):

This is the same answer I posted to [this, similar, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014175).

Assuming that array `$binary` is a previously constructed array bytes (like monochrome bitmap pixels in my case) that you want written to the disk in this exact order, the below code worked for me on an AMD 1055t running ubuntu server 10.04 LTS.

I iterated over every kind of answer I could find on the Net, checking the output (I used either shed or [vi, like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441399/946112)) to confirm the results.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($base.".bin", "w");
$binout=Array();
for($idx=0; $idx < $stop; $idx=$idx+2 ){
    if( array_key_exists($idx,$binary) )
        fwrite($fp,pack( "n", $binary[$idx]<<8 | $binary[$idx+1]));
    else {
        echo "index $idx not found in array \$binary[], wtf?\n";
    }
}
fclose($fp);
echo "Filename $base.bin had ".filesize($base.".bin")." bytes written\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function -- it gives you a decent amount of control over how you want your values structured as well, i.e., 16 bits or 32 bits at a time, little-endian versus big-endian, etc.