# Writing Binary Data from Hex String in PHP

Tags: php, string, hex, fwrite

I'm trying to write a binary file from hex string.
For example, if my hex string is `C27EF0EC`, then the hex file should contain **ASCII** characters for `C2`, `7E`, `F0` and `EC`.
How do I do this in `PHP`?

Here's what I've tried:

```
$s="";
for ($i=0; $i<count($h); $i++) {
    $s+=pack("C*", "0x".$h[$i]);
}
$f2=fopen("codes0", "wb+");
fwrite($f2, $s);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I believe you may find your answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488538/convert-hex-to-ascii-characters

Comment: @MarkReed I edited it to my post.

Comment: @Taicho I didn't mean that.

Answer (score 2):

So the first thing you need to do is turn your single string into an array of two-character strings with `str_split`.

```
$hex_bytes = str_split($h, 2);
```

Then you want to convert each of those values from a hexadecimal string to the corresponding number with `hexdec`.

```
$code_array = array_map(hexdec, $hex_bytes);
```

Then you want the byte value corresponding to each of those character codes, which you can get with `chr`:

```
$char_array = array_map(chr, $code_array);
```

Finally, you want to join all those bytes together into a single string, which you can do with `implode`.

```
$s = implode($char_array);
```

You can use the steps above in that order, or you can put it all together into one expression like this:

```
$s = implode(array_map(chr, array_map(hexdec, str_split($h,2))));
```

Note that as soon as you get a value above 0x7F it's no longer "ASCII".

Comment: And it's still the same. :(

Comment: Then you did something else wrong, because that yields a completely different result from your code.

Comment: See edit. Your code was treating `$h` as an array of strings instead of a single string.

Comment: Got these errors:  Notice: Use of undefined constant chr - assumed 'chr' in C:\xampp\htdocs\codebase\index.php on line 2106

Notice: Use of undefined constant hexdec - assumed 'hexdec' in C:\xampp\htdocs\codebase\index.php on line 2106

Comment: You must have an older version of PHP.  Use strings for the function arguments: `'chr'`, `'hexdec'`, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21611/discussion-between-gskartwii-and-mark-reed)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that array `$binary` is a previously constructed array bytes (like monochrome bitmap pixels in my case) that you want written to the disk in this exact order, the below code worked for me on an AMD 1055t running ubuntu server 10.04 LTS.

I iterated over every kind of answer I could find on the Net, checking the output (I used either shed or [vi, like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441399/946112)) to confirm the results.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($base.".bin", "w");
$binout=Array();
for($idx=0; $idx < $stop; $idx=$idx+2 ){
    if( array_key_exists($idx,$binary) )
        fwrite($fp,pack( "n", $binary[$idx]<<8 | $binary[$idx+1]));
    else {
        echo "index $idx not found in array \$binary[], wtf?\n";
    }
}
fclose($fp);
echo "Filename $base.bin had ".filesize($base.".bin")." bytes written\n";
?>
```