# How to corrupt header of tar.gz for testing purpose

Tags: linux

How to corrupt header of tar.gz for testing purpose? So that when the application tries to unzip it ... it fails.

Thanks

Comment: Write a random byte to a random location. You have a 99.5% chance of damaging the file. What could be simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's awfully simple to create a file that gzip won't recognize:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=1 of=bad.tar.gz
```

While of course it's possible to create a valid gzip file with `/dev/urandom`, it's about as likely as being struck by lightning.  Under a clear sky.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself a [hex editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux), that previous questions recommends [bless](http://home.gna.org/bless/).

You can try arbitrarily changing bits but if you want to be more surgical take a look at the [gzip spec](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html) which can tell you exactly which bits to flip on the outer gzip header. Or try the [tar specification](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html).

There are checksums embedded in gzip files, those may be a good first choice to change:

> If FHCRC is set, a CRC16 for the gzip header is present, immediately
>   before the compressed data. The CRC16 consists of the two least
>   significant bytes of the CRC32 for all bytes of the gzip header up to
>   and not including the CRC16