# Print a Bitarray array into a document.dat

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to print in a documents bits 1 an 0  and I have the next code

```
from bitarray import bitarray

a = bitarray()
a.append(True)
a.append(False)
a.append(True)

print(a)

f = file("bits.dat","wb")
f.write(a)
f.close()
```

It seems that it works but when I open the document bit.dat appears an error that I do not known how to solve.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a hex editor to open that file, for example:

- [GHex - a hex editor for GNOME](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Ghex)
- [Bless Hex Editor](http://home.gna.org/bless/)
- More Suggestions: [stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux)

When I view the (bits.dat) file in a hex editor I get the following.

```
00000000:  b1                                                           :.
```

Answer (score 0):

I seems you are just opening the file in a wrong way – you are opening it as if it contained text, which is not the case. The viewer tries to interpret the data as UTF-8-encoded text, but the byte you've made is not valid UTF-8. Just try to view the file as binary data.

Comment: Do you know how con I change the view mode to binary?

Comment: @victor: That's application specific. Maybe the select at the bottom that says “Plain Text” could be changed to something like “Binary”.

Comment: I have already proved some of the diferent options and they did not work

Comment: @victor: You can also display the contents of the file interactively in Python.