# Open/Crack zip and disover his password

Tags: linux, security, zip

In a lesson of Computer Security our teacher showed us how to find out the password of a zip.

I tried his steps at home but now I'm stuck:

1. Created 2 zip with same file: `plain_zip.zip` without password and `encrypted_zip.zip` with a 4 characters psw: `1234`
2. Create another zip with another file: `plain_zip_2.zip` and `encrypted_zip_2.zip`.
3. Show through terminal his header (I don't remember the command line) and see that both: `plain_*.zip` and `encrypted_*.zip` has similar lines
4. Through a `XOR operation` between encrypted and plain zip find out the password. (He told us that's possible only if the password is 4 characters)

Now someone can tell me if these steps are correct? And moreover, how can see the header of a file? (I tried with: `head -n 1 plain_zip.zip` without success)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ok, I've installed bless... but now, how can I find the password? The XOR doesn't give me my password. Can someone explain the procedure?

Comment: What was the archive created with? I thought AES was the standard for this kind of thing, and I don't think AES has any known plaintext attacks.

Comment: What your teacher is referring to is detailed in section 3.6 of the BIham & Kocher plaintext attack (A Known Plaintext Attack on the PKZIP Stream Cipher).