# Hex Editor for Linux with auto update feature

Tags: linux, unix, hex, edit

Does anyone know of a way to see file in Hex on Linux so that the view is updated when a file on Disk changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vim. To switch into hex mode type:

```
:%!xxd
```

To exit from hex mode hit escape again and type:

```
:%!xxd -r
```

Also check out [how to edit binary file on the unix systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839227/how-to-edit-binary-file-on-the-unix-systems)